# Any way to reuse an identifier within a scope?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, scope, name-mangling

Normally using the same identifier like name of a variable for something like another variable within the same scope generates error by compiler, Is there any technique to actually indicate to compiler that in this scope up to this specific point this name has its own purpose and is used to refer to this variable but after this point the same name is going to refer to something else like another variable with another purpose?

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would make the code quite hard to read and maintain.

Comment: The term "label" is normally used for goto and switch/case targets... "identifier" would be less confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean variables, no, there's not. When you create a variable, it's tied to a specific type and a specific location. Having said that, there's nothing stopping you from re-using the same variable for two different things:

```
float f = 3.141592653589;
// do something with f while it's PI
f = 2.718281828459;
// now do something with f while it's E.
```

You can use a pointer so that it can be changed to point to a different variable but that's not what you're asking, I suspect. In any case, unless you use a void pointer and cast it, it's still tied to a specific type:

```
float pi = 3.141592653589;
float e  = 2.718281828459;
float *f = &pi;
// do something with *f while it's PI
f = &e;
// now do something with *f while it's E.
```

If what you're proposing is something like:

```
float f = 3.141592653589;
// do something with f while it's PI
forget f;
std::string f = "hello";
// do something with f while it's "hello"
forget f;
```

I'm not sure I see the point. I think you could do that by putting the definitions within a new scope (i.e., braces):

```
{
    float f = 3.141592653589;
    // do something with f while it's PI
}
{
    std::string f = "hello";
    // do something with f while it's "hello"
}
```

but it's not as if we have a world-wide shortage of variable names. And, if you're naming your variables well, it's pretty unlikely that a string and a float would even have the same name (double and float maybe but it's still an dubious function to add to the language).

Comment: +1 for answer and words "world-wide shortage of variable names" :)

Comment: "world-wide shortage..." trivialises the issue, which can legitimately arise in the context of macro expansions... introducing new scopes is generally sufficient.  (Another possibility is moving a single pointer through successive pointed-to targets... that way *p = 3 can affect different variables throughout the scope.)

Comment: I find I have zero need for macros any more, what with inline functions and enumerations (the only two things I ever really used them for), and my scopes are already pretty secure since my functions are kept small and my classes obey the minimum coupling, maximum cohesion principle.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can use blocks within the function, each of which creates its own scope.

```
void func(void)
{
   int a;
   {
      int b;
      // here a can be used and b is an int
   }
   {
      double b;
      // here a can still be used, but int b went out of scope
      // b is now a double and has no relationship to int b in the other block
   }
}
```

Comment: very nice, never noticed I could introduce new scopes using braces this way.

Answer (score 0):

Good fun when people ask about the extremely obscure corner cases of the language. One suspects a homework question (the one who posed the question would almost have to know "the" answer). But anyways, ...

```
#include <iostream>

struct ouch { int x; };
void ouch( ouch ) { std::cout << "ouch!" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    struct ouch ah = {};
    ouch( ah );
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

```
void fn()
{
    int a = 1;
#define a b
    int a = 2;
}
```

but... a bit pointless to even try this though, right?

Comment: Aarrgghh! If I find out where you live, you're in _big_ trouble :-)

Comment: just look for the house with unbalanced braces, dirty sandbox, and unstable foundation. I will warn you though, i have inclusion guards at the gate. :))